# Persistent text in a QTreeView delegate during edit mode

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I'm using a `QTreeView` with the default delegate to display editable model data.  When I double-click or press F2 on the field I want to change, I get the text edit box, but the existing text is erased when the editor appears.  I want the existing text to remain but become selected.  The "editable tree model" example from the Qt documentation has this behavior exactly, however I can't for the life of me figure out how it is accomplished.  The example does not use a custom delegate as far as I can tell and there are no calls related to delegate behavior that I can find.  Can this be done without a custom delegate?

Edit: here's my code for the reimplemented `QAbstractItemModel::data()`:

```
QVariant projectModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    node* item = static_cast<node*>(index.internalPointer());

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant(item->data(index.column()).c_str());

    else if (role == Qt::ForegroundRole)
        return item->text_color(index.column());

    else if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole)
        return item->background_color(index.column());

    else if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole)
        return item->check_state(index.column());

    else if (role == Qt::DecorationRole)
        return item->icon(index.column());

    else if (role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole)
        return item->text_alignment(index.column());

    else
        return QVariant();
}
```

Comment: Check what your model returns as `Qt::EditRole`

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean.  Qt::EditRole evaluates to "0n2" in my debug window, but that should be a constant value, not dependent on my model.

Comment: Your model should return a data, that you want to see in ediitor, via `Qt::EditRole`. If data is invalid (`QVariant::isValid() == false`) then editor will request data via `Qt::DisplayRole`

Comment: Show us the data() function of your model.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I changed the line `if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)` to `if (role == Qt::DisplayRole || Qt::EditRole)` and it magically works.  Thank you very much (you too, Silicomancer).  Repost your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model should return a data, that you want to see in ediitor, via `Qt::EditRole`. If data is invalid `(QVariant::isValid() == false)` then editor will request data via `Qt::DisplayRole`.